# JAXB annotations to deal with same element name in different namespaces

Tags: java, annotations, jaxb, xml-namespaces

The problem that I am trying to solve is that JAXB cannot handle the parent and inherited objects of the same name in different namespaces.

I have two schemas:

**schemaA.xsd**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:A="...">
<xs:complexType name="mytype">
...
```

**schemaB.xsd**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:B="..." xmlns:A="...">
<xs:import namespace="..." schemaLocation="schemaA.xsd"/>
<xs:complexType name="mytype">
...
```

Here the `mytype` definition is different in **schemaB**.  And no, I have no control over the schemas, they are large commercial thirdparty supplied.  How do people deal with this situation?  The point is that **schemaB** references **schemaA** and indeed uses many elements from **schemaA**.  JAXB cannot run on `B` alone, but it can and does on `A` alone.

One last point, there are many many elements involved, cannot add JAXB customization to all of them. Well it would be a lot of work.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are the "element names" toy refer to in the subject? What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

Funny how the JAXB questions get hardly any response.

@jamh

I assume you're trying to run xjc to generate Java stubs for the third party schema(s).  Have you tried specifying a different package name for each namespace?  This can be done in a custom binding file or on the command line with the -p argument...

xjc -p com.your.package.name /path/to/xsd

Answer (score 0):

In element declaration you need to provide different propertyName:

```
<xs:element ref="namespace1:foo">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:appinfo>
            <jaxb:property name="fooElement"/> // here you see changing the name
        </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
```

Doing so when you have two elements with name "foo" and one of them has a declaration, when one of them does not.

You will have generated (by xjc) an object with properties:

```
Foo foo;
Foo fooElement;
```

So there will no conflict.

You can read more about bindings on: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html